# cordova build ios but error in 'Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined'

Tags: cordova, xcode11

I use ionic3 and cordova@8.1.2. Recently my Xcode update to 11.1 and error occured [Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined].I tried this way:
change:

```
if (device.name === deviceType.name.replace(/\-inch/g, ' inch') &&
    device.availability.toLowerCase().indexOf('unavailable') < 0) {
    availAcc.push(device);
 }
```

to:

```
if (device.name === deviceType.name.replace(/\-inch/g, ' inch')) {
if ((device.availability && device.availability.toLowerCase().indexOf('unavailable') < 0)
|| device.isAvailable == 'YES') {
// XCode 10 and lower
availAcc.push(device);
}
}
```

Then error occurred in

```
Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

I cannot find where is this 'name'.

Answer (score 11):

Remove platform ios and again add platform ios.
It's working for myself.

```
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add ios
```

Comment: Ididnt change my code and it still error with
`Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

My cordova version is 8.1.2. I encountered the same problem recently on ios.Please check your Android or Ios version and make it to latest if you're using older version of it. You don't need to add/modify any code to list-emulator-build file(cordova/lib/list-emulator-build).
It'll be certainly working. latest version of ios is ios(5.0.1).

Answer (score 0):

Steps to solve this error:

1. Connect your iPhone device.
2. Open Xcode and select your iPhone device.
3. Run command in terminal: `ionic cordova build ios`